# Choose ranges from each row in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D numpy array and I need to select ranges from each row of that array, i.e. I need to do something like:

```
arr = arr[:, 3:6]
```

But instead of `3` and `6` I would like to use two 1D arrays, which contain starting and ending indices of required ranges.

- `arr` rows are packed of coordinates data.
- The length of each range is the same and is known beforehand.
- Starting and ending indices are aligned to the length of range (e.g. if the length of packed data is 3 then the length of the range is also 3 and starting and ending indices are multiples of 3)

How can I do that in numpy (I need it to be efficient vectorised implementation)?

Example:

```
arr = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
                [4,5,6,7]])
str_idx = [0, 2]
end_idx = [2, 4]
```

Wanted result:

```
selected = [[0,1],
            [6,7]]
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the starting and ending index arrays? are you looking for something like
start_ind = [1,4,2]
end_ind = [5,8,6]
so arr[:, start_ind:end_ind] will give you 1:5 for the first row, 4:8 for the second row, etc?

Comment: Solution to question given by @Divakar worked for me.